# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'core' of undefined

Tags: angular

I develop a front-end application in Angular 4.
I have a error in my browser console, the application works normally but I would like to remove this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'core' of undefined
at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:9:35)
at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:10:3)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js (ng-bootstrap.js?6c12:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f869e51aadb3d665a815:54)
at Object.1 (scripts.bundle.js:65)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f869e51aadb3d665a815:54)
at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap f869e51aadb3d665a815:25)
at scripts.bundle.js:1
```

Do you know why I have this error ? Maybe you would like to see parts of my code ?

Here my angular-cli.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "AIE"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js",
        "../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know if the problem is here, this error exist in all the application.

Comment: post your code where you get the error

Comment: this is symbol mapping issue as far as I know, can you post your `angular-cli.json` or `SystemJS` code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting the ng-bootstrap library inside scripts section of the CLI. Remove that and the error should go away.

Remove the following from your `"scripts": []` section:

> "../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js",

You should rather import symbols from the `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` in you component.ts.

Comment: Well done ! I have removed all the scripts in the angular-cli and it's work :) Thank you very much